# i got invalid request response from google maps api in python when I copy the link to chrome it works fine

Tags: python, google-maps-api-3

What can be the reson?

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "INVALID_REQUEST"
}
```

in Chrome fine:

```
{
"html_attributions": [],
"next_page_token": "CqQDkgEAAFOOGlx1ov_HPteOZTqmNHkYFmUDfDDmlQn0XpcBzeYWgCNmexMAOS1KRvaStWwFRvLDDKEUsGyFwguXrBHTuvdfmu4REV4VPH-ALqsxb7cl9wrRLhUQTyjnMilf68qgafL2Eb7GZ3OXH2s4vpsC2HRaclVPbp53kz1NZY7NeKDNPzUOW-tIHpw_X3U_2NhfUbDu-1gMFOOaMCOoaQt7FHW51ktIm4UFrn6OfytS_VdIp7RgOMp1HISIbx8GW2l1MKnUZaPEztlwJi3OvK9n4waWOvS7uUd_PPy1xPYJWv-yKtG3Ehok-LOjCv-jkB_Ki4uqjWCGW4kD5L_aKp2gjECT-ny-1aTpjtJc8a9p1Fhx_Wdbf2vee5hCZfbaSxseRgsHd0POFPaIFwIZYg6GJHHkbjW6gfbnI67oI9nC3dTH86gWzyFCsG_n0hyhCg-oHzO3mxlaDDxCM6xv1Nbp5AY4u03NGIpzTNoRekJ-EtA1d7cYu-yZ2XFzHXJGkxyWHobe_UdwLa6b4ZUQD8qCoKGQ429MxeY6x5R05AYg4Q1BEhA7UkpwystS_CoYKCCJXeoZGhRToQEqwA-RwiEMbAqwfN3n89aVZg",
"results": [...],
"status": "OK"
}
```

The code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib
import json
import csv
import hashlib
import time


YOUR_API_KEY = "SECRET"


def geocode(addr):
    url = ("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/"
           "geocode/json?address=%s&sensor=false") % (urllib.quote(addr))
    data = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    info = json.loads(data).get("results")[0].get("geometry").get("location")
    return info


def geocode2(r):
    info = []

    url_base = ("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?"
                "location=%s,%s&radius=500&types=food&sensor=false&"
                "key=%s&pagetoken=%s") % (
                r['lat'],
                r['lng'],
                YOUR_API_KEY,
                ''
                )

    data = urllib.urlopen(url_base).read()
    info.extend(json.loads(data).get("results"))
    token = json.loads(data).get("next_page_token")

    while token:
        time.sleep(5)
        new_url = url_base + token
        data = urllib.urlopen(new_url).read()
        token = json.loads(data).get("next_page_token")
        info.extend(json.loads(data).get("results"))

    print len(info)

    l = []
    for i in info:
        t = (i["name"],
            i["vicinity"],
            i["geometry"]["location"]["lat"],
            i["geometry"]["location"]["lng"]
            )

        l.append(t)
    return l


for place in geocode2(geocode('Polska, Warszawa, Pl. Zawiszy 1')):
    print place
```

The output:
https://gist.github.com/andilab/078ea76b1f4d70704b50

Comment: You should show your request code

Comment: I guess it is much about time. I added `time.sleep(5)` in while loop where i try fetching new google places with next_page_token() and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it is much about time. I added time.sleep(5) in while loop where I try fetching new google places with next_page_token() and it works.

The quota from docs confirms my guess.

> The maximum number of results that can be returned is 60. **There is a
>   short delay between when a next_page_token is issued, and when it will
>   become valid.**

From: [Google Places API Doc](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search)

Worth mention, that anyway maximum number of places returned will be **60**!